# VS2017 c++ ifstream error

Tags: c++

I've just installed Visual Studio to start writing C++ there, I spent the last year learning in CodeBlocks and everything was going fine. But when I got to trying out the ifstream function, it shoots out an error and I've looked around and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Could you guys please help?

Here's the very simple code that I wrote:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m[100];
    ifstream f1("in.txt");
    f1 >> n;
    for (int i; i < n; i++)
    {
        f1 >> m[i];
        cout << m[i] << endl;
    }
    f1.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the in.txt path 
C:\Users\Administratar\source\repos\ConsApp1\in.txt

And this is what is inside in.txt

```
4
1
2
3
4
```

And the error says:
"Error: Unable to open file
C:\Users\Administratar\source\repos\ConsApp1\Debug\ConsApp1.obj
Error code = 0x80070002"

Comment: You should try rebuilding the project and post here complete build log.

Comment: Your project working directory is not the same as the folder containing the file "in.txt".  Use a full pathname for the file.

Comment: File should be in Bin dir?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

Comment: Could be related https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79286/unable-to-open-source-files-with-error-0x80070002.html

Comment: 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Administratar\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========                       @VTT

Comment: I just tested it on VS2017, works fine after fixing the initialization of loop for.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp even after I fixed the for loop (thank you btw, silly mistake on my behalf), it still gives out the same error.

Comment: By default Visual Studio sets project directory as working directory so there is no need to adjust anything as long as "in.txt" is inside of project directory (which seems to be the case).

Comment: Build succeeds, where does that error come from (and when)?

Comment: @KillzoneKid yea, that was the first article that I found, but it didn't help too much, seeing as VS customer support doesn't do much.

Comment: @VTT I have no idea where the error comes from, it just appears every time that I debug and is always "Error: Unable to open file C:\Users\Administratar\source\repos\ConsApp1\Debug\ConsApp1.obj Error code = 0x80070002"

Comment: Where does it appear then? Can you run executable outside of VS?

Comment: @Ron K: Try to run VS2017 as admin.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Actually I'm just going to google it, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now, actually, but the problem wasn't in ifstream or the include at all. It was in the file included previous of it.
Just check stdafx.h file and make sure there's no issues or errors in it and it shall work perfectly fine.